# Print the squared sum from a list of factors c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

From the list below, im trying to find a list of factors from 9799, so, i got the factors of 9799 which is 1, 41, 239 , 9799

So i squared each of these factors and sum up by calculator

Supposedly the sum of the squared factors are 96079204, and it can be square root to become 9802

supposedly this line of code is executable:

```
//squared_sum is the sum of each of the factors squared

if (fmod(squared_sum, sqrt(squared_sum)) == 0)
            cout<<"squared_sum: "<<squared_sum<<endl;
```

however when i run below codes, the above line cannot be executed, can anyone know what happened?
I tried to use calculator to count manually, and i got my logic right, just not sure what really happened.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<math.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    float squared_sum = 0;
    float range2 = 9799;

    for(float i=range2; i<= range2; i++)
    {
        squared_sum = 0;
        for(float j =1; j<= i; j++) //search the factors
        {
            if(fmod(i,j) == 0){
                cout<<"factors of "<<i <<" is "<<j<<endl;
                squared_sum += j*j;
            }
        }


        if (fmod(squared_sum, sqrt(squared_sum)) == 0)
            cout<<"squared_sum: "<<squared_sum<<endl;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Then I thought it is because of data type error that cause me the problem, so I changed all the data type to float, but still no differences and the same problem still occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trouble comes from the `float` type for the second loop:

```
for(float i = 1; i <= number; ++i);
```

Also, the use of this loop is redundant, you don't need here:

```
 for(float i=range2; i<= range2; i++) { // It will iterate only once
    squared_sum = 0; // Already 0 
    // ...
}
```

You need to change to this:

```
int main() {
    long long sum_sqrs = 0;
    long number = 9799;

    for(long i = 1; i <= number; ++i) {
        if(fmod(number, i) == 0) {
            cout << "factors of " << number << " is " << i <<endl;
            sum_sqrs += i*i;
        }
    }
    if (fmod(sum_sqrs, sqrt(sum_sqrs)) == 0)
        cout << "sum_sqrs: " << sum_sqrs << endl;
}
```

Example:

```
factors of 9799 is 1
factors of 9799 is 41
factors of 9799 is 239
factors of 9799 is 9799
sum_sqrs: 96079204
```

Comment: I think you have misunderstood my question. I want to take the factors, then sum up each of them. Such as (1x1) + (41x41) + (239x239) + (9799x9799) = 96079204. Then square root it become 9802 to see whether is it square rootable.   you can use your calculator to get that

Comment: Thanks, it does the trick. The loop that I put there, is actually just a prototype, because i was searching factors of not just 9799, but a vast range of other numbers, i will try to implement your method into my codes and try it. Thanks for your help !

Comment: @WongZiAo then it will be safer to iterate over a container of numbers, using this method.

Comment: Sure, but whats the long long for? I mean like i understand in vectors it is used to represent a 2d vector or something similar, but in here, how does it works?

Comment: @WongZiAo it has nothing to do with vectors of vectors, it is an integral type. Here, its purpose was to play it safe with large numbers. You can use an `unsigned` just as well.

Comment: alright  , i have understood it, thanks !

Comment: @WongZiAo check this [table](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types#Properties) for `long` and `long long`.

Comment: @WongZiAo also, you don't have to check all the factors of `n` up to `n`, you can just go up to the `sqrt(n)`.

Comment: Hi i have checked, indeed the long is very very important, i changed the data type of everything to long and it works. Because when there's no long, the sum of the each of the squared factors will less by 1 from the actual sum, i guess, is because of the 'long' thing

Comment: int main()
{
    long long squared_sum = 0;
    long range1 = 1;
    long range2 = 9799;

    for(long i=9799; i<= range2; i++)
    {
        squared_sum = 0;
        for(long j =1; j<= i; j++) //search the factors
        {
            if(fmod(i,j) == 0)
            {
                cout<<"factors of "<<i <<" is "<<j<<endl;
                squared_sum += j*j;
            }
        }

        if (fmod(squared_sum, sqrt(squared_sum)) == 0)
            cout<<"squared_sum: "<<squared_sum<<endl;
    }

Comment: You can execute it if you would like. I just remove the #include<iostream> and #include<math.h> , using namespace std and return 0

Comment: Thanks for your help ! I have been struggling on this for 8 hours from yesterday till today !

Comment: @WongZiAo you're welcome. Yeah, the type was crucial, I've edited it in the answer few minutes ago. Don't forget about check up to the `sqrt(n)`. Best of luck to you!